# Do chain levels affect Monograph drops?

Tags: ps4, final-fantasy-12

I've arrived at the point in The Zodiac Age's story where I'm beginning the materials grind for the Tournesol, a powerful greatsword. One of the required materials is 6 Hell Gate's Flame, dropped from Cerberus enemies in the Feywood. According to a Wiki source I read, the Cerberus has a 5% chance to drop a Hell Gate's Flame, so long as the player owns the Hunter's Monograph.

I noticed that even after chaining 100+ wolves, I did not receive any Hell Gate's Flame. After I stopped caring and put my speed on 4x, and annihilated absolutely every enemy in the zone repeatedly, I got 6 of them relatively quickly.

So, do chain levels affect your Monograph drops in any positive or negative way?

Comment: Not confident enough to post an answer, but I believe there are some special drops that don't get affected by chain level. This is probably one of them

Comment: Any feedback on that downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no positive or negative affects for Monograph drops as a result of your chain level. From the [Chain Wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Chain_(term)), drops through Monographs, as well as the Canopic Jar, are unaffected by your chain level

> There are two exceptions to this rule: drops as a result of monographs and the Canopic Jar are unaffected by Chain Level but will still drop from chained enemies normally, so the player can receive multiple items as normal drops along with monograph and Canopic Jar drops.

Comment: Sounds about right to me. I didn't realize that chains did nothing for special monograph drops, but I guess that makes sense. Don't want to make it too easy for me to get Hell Gate's Flame by having a 5% chance to drop 3 of them at a time :')